# ` (backtick) appearing in Cakephp view

Tags: php, cakephp, web-applications

A backtick appears in my rendered view in my cakephp application. They sometimes appear in two places:

1. At the very start of the body
2. After echo $this->Form->create();

I can't see a pattern that causes the problem. Is there a known problem that produces backticks?

Example of backtick appearing after `Form->create()`

```
<div class="users form">
<h2><?php echo __('Change password'); ?></h2>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input(
    'password_new',
    array(
        'label' => 'New Password',
        'type' => 'password',
        'div' => 'input password required',
        'required' => 'required',
    )
);
echo $this->Form->input(
    'password_new_confirm',
    array(
        'label' => 'New Password Again',
        'type' => 'password',
        'div' => 'input password required',
        'required' => 'required',
    )
);
echo $this->Form->end(__('Change password'));
?>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Back To Settings'), array('action' => 'settings',)); ?>
</div>
```

Screenshot of HTML output:
[image: Screenshot of HTML output:]

Comment: Have you done a "find" for a backtick character in your source code? :)

Comment: I can't be certain about this, but you have a comma at the end of both `'required' => 'required',`. Usually the last ones don't have one. *Just saying*.

Comment: It comes after `</h2>`, and before `echo $this->Form->create()`. Look at the code for that method. If you are on *nix then `cd` to your root folder, and run this: `grep -rin "\`" .` Look at every match that can possibly be the cause.

Comment: @Fred I think commas are sometimes left on (like that) in order to avoid having to add another comma when rearranging those sort of lines in the future.

Comment: @summea Thanks for letting me know. You should make yours as an **answer**, cheers ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noted in your answer, it sounds like the backtick ended up being in another file *(in this case, your User model file.)*

This is one of the downsides of working with CakePHP: text that is outside of your `<?php ... ?>` tags will be *rendered* to the final, outputted view that end users will see *(in addition to the actual "view" that was only supposed to be shown to the end user.)*

This can even happen when using an `echo` statement in a particular **controller**, as well.

For example, using:

```
echo 'random text that should not be displayed from a controller';
```

will result in displaying that "random text" in the final, outputted view.

Basically, CakePHP does not seem to enforce a super clean view "output" process *(and this is probably, in part, because of the way PHP inherently works...)* so it is mostly up to the developer to keep track of desired view output.

Answer (score 2):

Found a backtick in my User model, such an idiot, thanks Summea

Comment: Glad to see it was found :)